# Number format not matching between Pentaho Kettle and Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pentaho, kettle

I have a database table in Oracle 11g created and populated with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (CODE NUMBER(1,0));
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (CODE) VALUES (3);
```

Now, I want to use this table as a lockup table in a Pentaho Kettle transformation. I want to make sure that the value of a column comes from this table, and if not abort. I have the following setup:

[image: Transformation]

The data frame has a single column called `Test` of type integer, and a single row. The lookup is configured like this:

[image: Database lookup]

However the lookup always fail and the transformation is aborted, no matter if the value of `Test` is 3 (should be ok), or 4 (should be aborted). However, if I check the "Load all data from table" box, it works as expected.

So my question is this: Why does it not work unless I cache the whole table?

Two further observations:

- When it works, and the row is printed in log, I notice that `Test` is printed like `[ 3]` and `From DB` is printed like `[3]` (without the extra space). I don't know if this is of any significance, though.
- If I change the database table so that `CODE` is created as `INT`, it works. This leads me to believe it is somehow related to the number formatting. (In my actual application, I can not change the database tables.) I guess I should change the format of `Test`, but to what? Setting it to Number does not help, nor does Number with length 1 and precision 0.

Comment: I looks like the root of the issue is somewhere between the oracle11g jdbc and PDI's meta layer. Easiest thing you can do - throw in a table input step, `SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE`, right click and *Show output fields*. You should see the PDI equivalent of oracle11g's `NUMBER(1,0)`.

Comment: Weird to compare integer and numeric. Kettle written in Java so if Test field is "Integer" type and in database field code is numeric (with has own type in Java BigDecimal), then to compare those numbers might be non trivial.

Comment: @YuvalHerziger Thanks for the suggestion! According to "Show output fields" it is an integer with length 1, precision 0, decimal `,` and mask `#;-#`. However setting the format in the data grid to that does not help.

Comment: Now I am in the funny situation that if I replace the data grid with a table input, the database lookup claims that the field that was just read from the database does not exist in the database. I think it is fair to say that this is a bug.

Comment: Very strange @Anders ! Have you tried to mask it to Integer after fetching it from the database, using *Select values* under the *Meta-data* tab? I know it sounds rather silly, never hurts to try though.

Comment: Again - thanks for the suggestion, @YuvalHerziger! It does not help, though. I'm starting to think that I should just live with cashing all the data. At least it is good to know that someone else thinks it is strange, and I am not just missing something obvious.

Comment: @Anders - I'd go down the same path, too. Plus, usually you'd aspire to leave a database server as least harassed as you can, and the database lookup step could be quite costly in that respect. If you could do the operation with persistent storage on the transformation server that would be better, in my honest opinion.